# How to increase the size of a pane and scroll around in javafx?

Tags: javafx

I have a grid node at the center of a pane and 10 other grid nodes are added around it which appear on the screen. But when i try to increase the no. of grid nodes to 20 most of them go off screen.  Is there a way to increase the size of the pane and scroll it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your `GridPane` into a `ScrollPane`:

```
GridPane gridPane = ...
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
scrollPane.setContent(gridPane);
```

See some more examples: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0350__JavaFX_ScrollPane.htm